# Dirac neutrinos?

Tags: charge, fermions, dirac-equation, antimatter, neutrinos

How can Dirac neutrinos exist if neutrinos have no charge? As far as I'm aware, the antiparticle of a particle is its charge conjugate while all of its other characteristics remain same. How then can a neutrino be distinct from an antineutrino?

Comment: Charge conjugation is well-defined for chargeless fermions. It reverses flavor, fermion number, etc. Read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric charge is not the only quantum number. [Neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) are distinguished as follows.

Particle: chirality: Left, weak isospin +$\frac{1}{2}$, lepton nr: +1,

Anti-Particle: chirality: Right, weak isospin -$\frac{1}{2}$, lepton nr: -1,